# Time Series with Gaps in R

Tags: time-series

I am trying to set a time series in R. However, I a data of daily trading. Trading takes places 5 days a week. Hence, there are gaps in the times series. I want to set the time series without filling the gaps. I tried `ts()` function but it only works when there are no gaps.

```
ncw2 = ts(ncw1, start = c("2020-01-23", 1), freq=365)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the "zoo" library. It allows you to set time series with gaps.

```
library(zoo)
df <-  data.frame(
date <- c("2003-01-02", "2003-01-05", "2003-01-19"),
values <- c(3,8,1)
)
colnames(df) <- c("date", "values")

df.ts <- zoo(df[,-1], order.by = as.Date(df[,1], "%Y-%M-%d"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I could not understand the values here. I am not putting date manually, rather I already have a variable that has values of date.